# Strange behaviour of Titanium SDK - tab must have only one child

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I have tabbed app:

```
<Alloy>
<TabGroup navBarHidden="true">
    <Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
               <Require src="login" type="view" /> 
    </Tab>
    <Tab title="Tab 2" icon="KS_nav_views.png" id="register_home">
           <Require src="register" type="view" /> 
    </Tab>
</TabGroup>
```

My views:

```
<Alloy>
<Window title="Login" fullscreen = "true" orientation="vertical" >

        </Window>
</Alloy>
```

But nevertheless I've got

```
   [ERROR] :  Tab must have only one child element, which must be a Window
[ERROR] :  Alloy compiler failed
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

I tried to clean the project, refresh, reboot the system - but nevertheless get the same result.

Comment: What version of Alloy / Ti SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using old Alloy version so you should update your alloy version then use it with latest ti sdk.

I also got this type of error when using old alloy so i recommended to use latest alloy version.